# extracting words broken up by white space & some specific characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract 'words' from a string, specifically 'date' string components.

```
oct 12:30
2023 09:05 04
%yyyy %hh:%ii %mm
mar 2, 1945 * matches "2," instead of 2"
mar 2,1945  * matches "2,1945" instead of "2" "1945"
mar2,1945   * ideally, "mar2" should be "mar" "2" 
01-02-03
04:05:06
```

I *think* I'm pretty close:
`((^|%|[0-9]).+?(?=[,:]|\W|$))`

but this is extracting "2,1945" as one item.
I tried `((^|%|[0-9]).+?(?=[[^,]:]|\W|$))` but that didn't help at all.

basically, I need every word broken up by white space, or non alphanumeric characters. (ie: :/- etc) as well as if they break the alpha/numeric pattern (ie: mar2 should match mar and 2 separately)

Comment: To not match `2,` try `*` instead of `+`. More generally, it seems to me that `[%a-zA-Z]+|\d+` would solve your task.

Comment: "10th of April, 2023" is a problem too... I guess I"m not as close as I thought.

Comment: [%a-zA-Z]+|\d+ - doesn't parse "%d%Od of %MM, %yyyy" well. Using "*" doesn't parse "10th of April, 2023"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what input could de provided, so I'm partially guessing here.

Based on combination of provided examples I would suggest to use this:

```
%?[a-zA-Z]+|%?\d+[a-zA-Z]*
```

It will match optional `%` followed by letters, or numbers and optional letters.

Example:

```
oct 12:30 : ['oct', '12', '30']
2023 09:05 04 : ['2023', '09', '05', '04']
%yyyy %hh:%ii %mm : ['%yyyy', '%hh', '%ii', '%mm']
mar 2, 1945 : ['mar', '2', '1945']
mar 2,1945 : ['mar', '2', '1945']
mar2,1945 : ['mar', '2', '1945']
01-02-03 : ['01', '02', '03']
04:05:06 : ['04', '05', '06']
10th of April, 2023 : ['10th', 'of', 'April', '2023']
%d%Od of %MM, %yyyy : ['%d', '%Od', 'of', '%MM', '%yyyy']
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/PyKjzz/1).

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks. That seems to do it... regex ain't easy...

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d{1,4}|\w{1,10}|%\w{1,4})
```

```
\d{1,4} match number 2 to 4 digits (for all numbers)
or 
\w{1,10} match 1 to 10 characters (for all months)
or 
%\w{1,4} match 2-4 characters start with %
```

[image]

```
mar2,1945 -> mar 2 1945
```

But `%5` is matched if you don't want it; change `\w` to `[a-zA-Z]` instead.

Comment: Thanks; I tried yours, but given "%d%Od of %MM, %yyyy
10th of April, 2023", it doesn't match %d, or "of"

Comment: try `(\d{1,4}|\w{1,10}|%\w{1,4})` I change the number of characters needed to match to 1 to 10 characters. "November" has eight characters

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex with 3 capturing groups :

```
([a-zA-Z]+)[ ,]*(\d+)\,\s*(\d{4})
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/PS2YBz/1)